# SQL Server 2 ways to get month totals but different results

Tags: sql-server, date

I'm trying to get month totals for a past month and tried two different ways, but although I should get the same result, often it's different.
These are the two methods I tried:

1. Using MONTH() and YEAR() with DATEADD():

   ```
   WHERE YEAR(SomeDate) = YEAR(DATEADD(mm,-6,GETDATE())) AND MONTH(SomeDate) = MONTH(DATEADD(mm,-6,GETDATE()))
   ```
2. Using DATEADD() to determine first and last day of a month:

   ```
   WHERE SomeDate >= DATEADD(mm, -6, DATEADD(D,(DATEPART(D, GETDATE())-1)*-1,GETDATE())) AND SomeDate <= DATEADD(mm, -5, DATEADD(D,DATEPART(D, GETDATE())*-1,GETDATE()))
   ```

I expect both of these methods to give me all results for August 2014 (now Feb 2015), but the second method sometimes leaves out certain results. I think this really doesn't make sense. Anyone who can clarify this?

Comment: Input data and expected result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the time on these dates:

Compare your query:

```
SELECT DATEADD(mm, -6, DATEADD(D,(DATEPART(D, GETDATE())-1)-1,GETDATE()))
```

To:

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(mm, -6, DATEADD(D,(DATEPART(D, GETDATE())-1)-1,GETDATE())) AS DATE)
```

Comment: Yes, you're right! I didn't consider the time at all. Casting as date gives me the same result for both! Thank you! m(_ _)m

Comment: After your solution I've also found another. using CONVERT(VARCHAR,<datestring>,###) also should work to remove the time factor.